# How can I show all dates?. Now my dates are available when sales have. I want to show all dates

Tags: postgresql

```
select date(products.date_of_sale) as Date,
count(case when products.product_type_id = 6 then product_types.id end) as "POYOYO"
and products.product_type_id = 55
and products.product_type_id = 55
and products.product_type_id = 55
from products
and products.product_type_id = 6
and products.product_type_id = 55
and products.product_type_id = 55
order by date(products.date_of_sale) desc
```

Now my dates show only sales have.and products.product_type_id = 55and products.product_type_id = 55

Answer (score 1):

You can use generate_series function in order to build a series of dates for which you want to build the series.
Lets say that you want a series from the first sale until last sale it would look like this.

```
with cte_sales as (
    select date(products.date_of_sale) as Date,
count(case when products.product_type_id = 6 then product_types.id end) as "Car_Rentals"
from products
join product_types on product_types.id = products.product_type_id
where date(products.date_of_sale) >= '2021-06-01'
and date(products.date_of_sale) <= current_date
and products.product_type_id = 6
and products.sales_category_id = 1
and products.sales_category_id <> 2
and products.status_id = 7
group by date(products.date_of_sale)
order by date(products.date_of_sale) desc
)
, cte_series as (
 select generate_series(min(Date), max(Date), '1 day'::interval)::date as generated_series
 from cte_sales)

select
 *
from
  cte_series series
left join
  cte_sales sales
on sales.Date = series.generated_series
```

You can play with different ways of generating series, it is a powerful function.

Comment: Ty martin. BTW how about with UNION function to my queries.

Comment: when I run your queries, it contains 3 column name generated_series, date,car_rentals. But I need 2 column date , car_rentals. How about this sir?

Comment: You can replace * from final select with naming columns that you want in your output. So instead of * you can do something like -> generated_series as date_of_sale, coalesce("Car_Rentals", 0) as "Car_Rentals".

Regarding Union, I don't see how you can use it for this case.